# How to test the search bar(input element) for the Materialtable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-table

I am trying to make a unit test for the search bar of the materialtable. But I didn't find a way to give the search bar(an input element) a test-id. I have tried to use `getByRole` to get the input element but I get the error "Unable to find an element by [role=input]"

```
test("should show the results properly after searching something", async () => {
    const selectedRowId = "DRQ000000000001";
    const lastDrawnRow = testDataRequests[0];
    const updateSelectedRow = jest.fn();

    const updateLastSelectedRow = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = render(
      <HistoricalDataSets
        testDataRequests={testDataRequests}
        selectedRowId={selectedRowId}
        lastDrawnRow={lastDrawnRow}
        updateSelectedRow={updateSelectedRow}
        updateLastSelectedRow={updateLastSelectedRow}
      />
    );
    const inputField = wrapper.getByRole("input");
    const searchText = "Fibre";
    fireEvent.change(inputField, { target: { searchText } });

    expect(wrapper.queryAllByText(/Fibre/)).toBeDefined();
    expect(wrapper.getAllByTestId("status-link").length).toBe(1);
  });
```

I have tried using `getElementsByClassName` to get the input element. But it does not work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9eIY.png) This is the html after rendering.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to use getByRole to get the input element but I get the error `"Unable to find an element by [role=input]"`

The role for an input element with `type="text"` or no `type` assigned isn't 'input', it's 'textbox' [(source)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance). This should let you select the correct element if you only have the one `<input type="text"/>`, though you may run into issues if you have more textbox inputs on the same page.